# Getting property 'url' does not exist on type 'Request'. while trying to run my nestJs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, package.json

I am running into this issue while I try to run my backend NestJs application using 'npm run start:dev'. I get the error: TSError: x Unable to compile typescript: Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Request'.
The application was running fine a few days ago and I am not sure what I did that caused this issue.
I am also getting: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Request'

Both of these issues are coming from the main.ts file.
This is the main.ts file:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors();
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.use('/', (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'api base route.' });
    }
    next();
  });

}
bootstrap();
```

I tried updating the node version to 18.16.4 and I also updated the nest version to v8. I uninstalled and reinstalled ts-node and typescript, express and @types/express versions.
But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the express and @types/express versions are same or not. Should match these versions. If not match these versions try downgrading or upgrading @types/express version.

Answer (score 0):

You can import **UrlWithParsedQuery** and **StatusCodes** in your code and You need to use them instead of Request's url and status properties

I have just updated your existing code. You can try with this below :-

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { UrlWithParsedQuery } from 'url';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors();

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.use('/', (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {

    const url = req.originalUrl as UrlWithParsedQuery;
    if (url.pathname === '/') {

        return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ message: 'api base route.' });
    }
    next();
  });
}

bootstrap();
```